# DataChannel.state() always returns CONNECTING webRTC Android

Tags: android, socket.io, webrtc, libjingle

I have an android app running as a client of WebRTC server running at Node.js server.
The current state of the app is I can make video calls but can't send the message on DataChannel.

Here is my complete code for the android app.

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends Activity {

    public List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers;
    private GLSurfaceView videoView;
    public static SocketIO socket;
    ArrayList<String> userIDs = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String FIELD_TRIAL_VP9 = "WebRTC-SupportVP9/Enabled/";
    String RoomId = "";
    String sreverURL = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/";
    private EditText roomid;
    private VideoRenderer.Callbacks remote_view;
    private VideoRenderer.Callbacks local_view;
    protected PeerConnectionFactory factory;
    PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = null;
    Events pc_events;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        videoView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glview_call_remote);
        VideoRendererGui.setView(videoView, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createPeerConnectionFactory();
            }
        });

        remote_view = VideoRendererGui.create(0, 0, 100, 100, ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT, false);
        local_view = VideoRendererGui.create(0, 0, 100, 100, ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, true);
        iceServers = new ArrayList<>();
        IceServer icc = new IceServer("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302", "", "");
        iceServers.add(icc);
        roomid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.roomId);
        Random rand = new Random();
        roomid.setText("" + rand.nextInt(9999));
        pc_events = new peerEventHandler();
    }

    private void createPeerConnectionFactory() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials(FIELD_TRIAL_VP9);
                PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(Home.this, true, true, true, VideoRendererGui.getEGLContext());
                try {
                    factory = new PeerConnectionFactory();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void ondail(View view) {

        try {

            try {
                SocketIO.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            socket = new SocketIO();

            socket.connect(sreverURL, new IOCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                    socketIOException.printStackTrace();
                }
                @Override
                public void onDisconnect() {
                }
                @Override
                public void onConnect() {
                    showToast("Connected to " + sreverURL);
                }
                @Override
                public void on(final String event, IOAcknowledge ack, final Object... args) {

                    Log.e("Socked.on", event + ", " + args);
                    switch (getEvent(event)) {

                        case LOG :
                            break;
                        case MESSAGE :
                            if (args instanceof Object[]) {
                                pc_events.setMessage(args[0].toString());
                            } else {
                                pc_events.setMessage(args.toString());
                            }
                            break;
                        case CREATED :
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    showToast("Room Created " + args[0]);
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        case BROADCAST :
                            break;
                        case JOIN :
                            break;
                        case EMIT :
                            Log.e("Socked.onEMIT", args.toString());
                            startCall();
                            pc_events.createOffer();
                            break;

                        case ERROR :
                            Log.e("Socked.onERROR", args.toString());
                            break;

                        default :

                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

            try {
                RoomId = roomid.getText().toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            socket.emit("create or join", RoomId);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void oncancel(View view) {

    }

    public SocketEvent getEvent(String eventString) {

        SocketEvent eventType;

        try {

            if (eventString.contains("log")) {
                eventType = SocketEvent.LOG;
            } else if (eventString.contains("created")) {
                eventType = SocketEvent.CREATED;
            } else if (eventString.contains("emit():")) {
                eventType = SocketEvent.EMIT;
            }

            else if (eventString.contains("broadcast():")) {
                eventType = SocketEvent.BROADCAST;
            } else if (eventString.contains("message")) {
                eventType = SocketEvent.MESSAGE;
            } else if (eventString.toLowerCase().substring(0, 20).contains("join")) {
                eventType = SocketEvent.JOIN;
            } else {
                eventType = SocketEvent.ERROR;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            eventType = SocketEvent.ERROR;
        }

        return eventType;

    }

    public static interface Events {

        public void peerConnectionEvent(VideoRenderer.Callbacks localRender, VideoRenderer.Callbacks remoteRender);

        public void setFactory(PeerConnectionFactory factory);

        public void setMessage(String message);
        public void createOffer();

        public void sendMessage(String msg);
    }

    private void startCall() {

        pc_events.setFactory(factory);

        pc_events.peerConnectionEvent(remote_view, local_view);

    }

    public void showToast(final String message) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeOffer(View v) {
        pc_events.sendMessage("Hello");
    }

}
```

**peerEventHandler.java**

```
public class peerEventHandler implements Events {

    private PeerConnection peerConnection;
    private PeerConnectionFactory factory;
    PCObserver pcObserver = new PCObserver();
    public LooperExecutor executor;

    private MediaStream mediaStream;

    private VideoSource videoSource;
    private DcObserver dc_observer;
    public static final String VIDEO_TRACK_ID = "ARDAMSv0";
    public static final String AUDIO_TRACK_ID = "ARDAMSa0";

    private VideoCapturerAndroid videoCapturer;
    private VideoTrack localVideoTrack;
    private VideoTrack remoteVideoTrack;
    public boolean preferIsac = false;
    public boolean videoCallEnabled = true;
    public boolean preferH264 = false;

    private SessionDescription localSdp;

    private final SDPObserver sdpObserver = new SDPObserver();

    public boolean isInitiator = false;
    private MediaConstraints sdpMediaConstraints;

    private VideoRenderer.Callbacks remote_view;
    private VideoRenderer.Callbacks local_view;
    private DataChannel dataChannel;

    @Override
    public void peerConnectionEvent(Callbacks remoteRender, Callbacks localRender) {

        this.remote_view = remoteRender;
        this.local_view = localRender;
        creatPeerConnection();

    }

    public void creatPeerConnection() {

        executor = new LooperExecutor();
        executor.requestStart();

        MediaConstraints pcConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        MediaConstraints audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        sdpMediaConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

        creatPcConstrains(pcConstraints);
        creatvideoConstraints(videoConstraints);
        creatsdpMediaConstraints(sdpMediaConstraints);

        List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<PeerConnection.IceServer>();

        IceServer iceServer = new IceServer("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302", "", "");

        iceServers.add(iceServer);

        PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers);

        rtcConfig.tcpCandidatePolicy = PeerConnection.TcpCandidatePolicy.DISABLED;
        rtcConfig.bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.BALANCED;
        rtcConfig.rtcpMuxPolicy = PeerConnection.RtcpMuxPolicy.NEGOTIATE;

        peerConnection = factory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, pcConstraints, pcObserver);

        Logging.enableTracing("logcat:", EnumSet.of(Logging.TraceLevel.TRACE_DEFAULT), Logging.Severity.LS_WARNING);

        mediaStream = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");

        String cameraDeviceName = CameraEnumerationAndroid.getDeviceName(0);
        String frontCameraDeviceName = CameraEnumerationAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice();

        cameraDeviceName = frontCameraDeviceName;

        videoCapturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(cameraDeviceName, null);

        videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer, videoConstraints);

        localVideoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_ID, videoSource);
        localVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
        localVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(local_view));
        mediaStream.addTrack(factory.createAudioTrack(AUDIO_TRACK_ID, factory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints)));
        mediaStream.addTrack(localVideoTrack);
        peerConnection.addStream(mediaStream);

        dataChannel = peerConnection.createDataChannel("sendDataChannel", new DataChannel.Init());
        dc_observer = new DcObserver();
        dataChannel.registerObserver(dc_observer);

    }

    @Override
    public void createOffer() {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (peerConnection != null) {
                    isInitiator = true;
                    peerConnection.createOffer(sdpObserver, sdpMediaConstraints);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void createAnswer() {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (peerConnection != null) {
                    isInitiator = false;
                    peerConnection.createAnswer(sdpObserver, sdpMediaConstraints);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class PCObserver implements PeerConnection.Observer {

        @Override
        public void onAddStream(final MediaStream stream) {

            Log.e("onAddStream", "onAddStream");
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (peerConnection == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (stream.audioTracks.size() > 1 || stream.videoTracks.size() > 1) {
                        // /reportError("Weird-looking stream: " + stream);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (stream.videoTracks.size() == 1) {
                        remoteVideoTrack = stream.videoTracks.get(0);
                        remoteVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
                        remoteVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(remote_view));
                        VideoRendererGui.update(local_view, 75, 70, 60, 60, ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT, true);
                        VideoRendererGui.update(remote_view, 0, 0, 200, 200, ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, false);
                    }
                }
            });



        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChannel(final DataChannel dc) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dataChannel = dc;
                    String channelName = dataChannel.label();
                    dataChannel.registerObserver(new DcObserver());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate candidate) {

            SocketIO socket = Home.socket;

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {

                json.putOpt("type", "candidate");
                json.putOpt("label", candidate.sdpMLineIndex);
                json.putOpt("id", candidate.sdpMid);
                json.putOpt("candidate", candidate.sdp);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            socket.emit("message", json);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceConnectionChange(IceConnectionState arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceGatheringChange(IceGatheringState arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSignalingChange(SignalingState arg0) {
        }

    }

    public void creatPcConstrains(MediaConstraints pcConstraints) {
        pcConstraints.optional.add(new KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
        pcConstraints.optional.add(new KeyValuePair("RtpDataChannels", "true"));
        pcConstraints.optional.add(new KeyValuePair("internalSctpDataChannels", "true"));
    }
    public void creatvideoConstraints(MediaConstraints videoConstraints) {

        String MAX_VIDEO_WIDTH_CONSTRAINT = "maxWidth";
        String MIN_VIDEO_WIDTH_CONSTRAINT = "minWidth";
        String MAX_VIDEO_HEIGHT_CONSTRAINT = "maxHeight";
        String MIN_VIDEO_HEIGHT_CONSTRAINT = "minHeight";
        String MAX_VIDEO_FPS_CONSTRAINT = "maxFrameRate";
        String MIN_VIDEO_FPS_CONSTRAINT = "minFrameRate";

        int videoWidth = 0;
        int videoHeight = 0;

        if ((videoWidth == 0 || videoHeight == 0) && true && MediaCodecVideoEncoder.isVp8HwSupported()) {
            videoWidth = 1280;
            videoHeight = 1280;
        }

        if (videoWidth > 0 && videoHeight > 0) {
            videoWidth = Math.min(videoWidth, 1280);
            videoHeight = Math.min(videoHeight, 1280);
            videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new KeyValuePair(MIN_VIDEO_WIDTH_CONSTRAINT, Integer.toString(videoWidth)));
            videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new KeyValuePair(MAX_VIDEO_WIDTH_CONSTRAINT, Integer.toString(videoWidth)));
            videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new KeyValuePair(MIN_VIDEO_HEIGHT_CONSTRAINT, Integer.toString(videoHeight)));
            videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new KeyValuePair(MAX_VIDEO_HEIGHT_CONSTRAINT, Integer.toString(videoHeight)));
        }

        int videoFps = 30;

        videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new KeyValuePair(MIN_VIDEO_FPS_CONSTRAINT, Integer.toString(videoFps)));
        videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new KeyValuePair(MAX_VIDEO_FPS_CONSTRAINT, Integer.toString(videoFps)));

    }
    public void creataudioConstraints(MediaConstraints pcConstraints) {
        pcConstraints.optional.add(new KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
        pcConstraints.optional.add(new KeyValuePair("RtpDataChannels", "true"));
        pcConstraints.optional.add(new KeyValuePair("internalSctpDataChannels", "true"));
    }
    public void creatsdpMediaConstraints(MediaConstraints sdpMediaConstraints) {

        sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"));

        sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"));

    }

    private class SDPObserver implements SdpObserver {

        @Override
        public void onCreateFailure(String arg0) {
            System.out.print(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription origSdp) {
            if (localSdp != null) {
                return;
            }
            localSdp = origSdp;
            setLocalDescription(origSdp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetFailure(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetSuccess() {

            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (peerConnection == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (isInitiator) {
                        if (peerConnection != null) {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                            try {
                                json.putOpt("type", localSdp.type.toString().toLowerCase());
                                json.putOpt("sdp", localSdp.description);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Home.socket.emit("message", json);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // createAnswer();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }
    public void addRemoteIceCandidate(final IceCandidate candidate) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setLocalDescription(final SessionDescription sdp) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (peerConnection == null) {
                    return;
                }
                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdpObserver, sdp);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setRemoteDescription(final SessionDescription sdp) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (peerConnection == null) {
                    return;
                }

                peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(sdpObserver, sdp);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setFactory(PeerConnectionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void onWebSocketMessage(final String msg) {

        try {
            Log.e("onWebSocketMessage", msg);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(msg);
            json = new JSONObject(msg);
            String type = json.optString("type");
            if (type.equals("candidate")) {
                IceCandidate candidate = new IceCandidate(json.getString("id"), json.getInt("label"), json.getString("candidate"));
                addRemoteIceCandidate(candidate);
            } else if (type.equals("answer")) {
                isInitiator = false;
                SessionDescription sdp = new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.fromCanonicalForm(type), json.getString("sdp"));
                setRemoteDescription(sdp);
            } else if (type.equals("offer")) {
                SessionDescription sdp = new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.fromCanonicalForm(type), json.getString("sdp"));
                setRemoteDescription(sdp);
            } else if (type.equals("bye")) {
            } else {
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        if (message.toString().contains("got user media") || message.toString().contains("bye")) {

        } else
            onWebSocketMessage(message);

    }

    private class DcObserver implements DataChannel.Observer {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(DataChannel.Buffer buffer) {

            ByteBuffer data = buffer.data;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[data.remaining()];
            data.get(bytes);
            String command = new String(bytes);

            Log.e("onMessage ", command);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStateChange() {
            Log.e("onStateChange ", "onStateChange");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferedAmountChange(long arg0) {
            Log.e("onMessage ", "" + arg0);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(msg.getBytes());
        boolean sent = dataChannel.send(new DataChannel.Buffer(buffer, false));
        if (sent) {
            Log.e("Message sent", "" + sent);
        }
    }
}
```

Any comments and suggestions are welcomed ;)

Comment: The code to add a data channel looks fine to me, except you can remove  the RtpDataChannels contraint. As I recall the data channel works through SCTP now

Comment: Thanks @GuyS I'll try and let you know soon

Comment: Thanks @GuyS It worked great, although there was a little change in Server end but your tip worked. Can you post it as answer so that I accept it and might help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebRTC data channel works through SCTP now so you can remove the RtpDataChannels constraint.